# Class comparisons (like __ge__) without functools total_ordering

Tags: python, class, magic-methods

The following code works, but surprisingly also for the methods that have not been implemented.
Normally you need [total_ordering](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) to accomplish this, right?

```
class Account:

    def __init__(self, balance=0):
        self.balance = balance

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.balance < other.balance

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self.balance <= other.balance


acc1 = Account(100)
acc2 = Account(200)

print(acc1 < acc2)   # True
print(acc1 >= acc2)  # False, but __ge__ is not defined
print(acc1 == acc2)  # False, but __eq__ is not defined
```

Is it safe to do this without `total_ordering` or will this lead to surprises?

Comment: Without `__eq__` the equality comparison falls back to *identity*. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things are happening here.

The first is that `==` is *always defined* by default, inherited from `object.__eq__`. Essentially it, works by identity, which is *not* what you expect here.

The second is described in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__):

> There are no swapped-argument versions of these methods (to be used
> when the left argument does not support the operation but the right
> argument does); rather, `__lt__()` and `__gt__()` are each other’s
> reflection, `__le__()` and `__ge__()` are each other’s reflection, and
> `__eq__()` and `__ne__()` are their own reflection.

So, this is like `__add__` and `__radd__`. In the case of `acc1 >= acc2`, the left operand does not support `__gt__`, so this is delegated to the right operand's `__le__`.

Comment: Ok I see. So by just adding "\_\_eq\_\_" to my class I basically accomplish the same as `total_ordering`?

Comment: @PythonSherpa in effect, yes. AFAIKT.

Comment: @PythonSherpa note, the other operands are actually implemented too in `object` to return `NotImplemented` which you should be using to follow the protocol correctly